# Can anyone suggest a good Data Modelling Tool/ Data modeler that natively supports multiple databases?

Tags: mysql, windows, oracle, postgresql, data-modeling

Could you recommend me a good and affordable db modeling tool for Windows?

It'll be mainly used for the two major open source databases: MySQL and PostgreSQL and the two most popular commercial databases: Oracle and SQL Server. I hope all these databases can be connected natively and simultaneously within a single application. It'll be great if it would have an intuitive GUI. .

Comment: Try this tool for SQL Server Physical models.

Info can be found here...

https://www.facebook.com/DataModelerTool/

or here...

https://plus.google.com/108968161662966473138

Answer (score 2):

I recently looked at [DbSchema](http://www.dbschema.com/) which looked very good.

I also looked at [DbWrench](http://www.dbwrench.com/) which has a similar feature set and price but was a lot slower when dealing with large models (> 250 tables)

We finally ended up purchasing [Toad Data Modeler](http://www.quest.com/toad-data-modeler/) (TDM) because support for database specific features is a bit better there and it's scripting ability allowed us to generate other export formats as well

See splash's answer for a link to a "free" version - it will expire in November 2012 so it's not really free. I don't know if there will be a new offer after that.

If you need a tool that runs on other platforms as well (TDM is Windows only) DbSchema seems to be good choice. It's auto-layout algorithm looked far better than TDM's

Comment: Relating to Toad Data Modeler Freeware: "the expiration period extends further every time a new free version is released" (http://modeling.inside.quest.com/click.jspa?searchID=2517291&messageID=122100)

Comment: @splash: thanks, I didn't see that comment ;)

Answer (score 1):

I have used [MySQL Workbench](http://mysqlworkbench.org/) which is cross platform. And it can be run from portable devices also. This can be used only with MySQL.

Comment: MySQL Workbench is a solution, but it tends to be extremely buggy. And the situation does not get any better version after version. I hoped v.6 would have been better, but it is also annoying as previous versions. It is not for serious work, bugs arise from anywhere. The big plus is that it's a native Linux application (not Java based).

Answer (score 0):

I've used [Navicat](http://www.navicat.com/) which is cross platform and not that expensive, they have separate tools for separate databases though so if you are going to use it for different DB systems you might need to purchase separate licenses for each, not 100% sure though.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [freeware edition of the Toad Data Modeler](http://toadworld.com/Freeware/ToadDataModelerFreeware/tabid/637/Default.aspx). Toad Data Modeler supports Oracle database, MS SQL Server, MySQL, PostgreSQL, MS Access and other database platforms.

It has certain limitations (see [Feature Matrix](http://modeling.inside.quest.com/servlet/KbServlet/download/4557-102-20702/TDM4_Feature_Matrix.pdf)) like:

- maximum of 25 entities
- maximum of 5 users within Licensee's organization

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard about MicroERD?
I think it's not been a long time since it was launched.
But try its demo.
It has full functions for data modeling.
And its price is quite reasonable.

http://www.microerd.com